# Is it correct to think of a Java Interface as a "contract" that a class must implement?

Tags: java, interfaces

I just want to check that my current understanding of Java interfaces is correct.

If an interface says it must include `public void increase(int amount)`, then does that just mean the class that implements that interface must have a matching method?

Comment: What happens if it's missing?

Comment: Try compiling it without and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct in general.

However, it is also possible for an abstract class to declare that concrete subclass should implement an interface without implementing methods.

The signature of the method implementing a method in interface must have matching parameters but the resulting value may be a subtype.

```
interface X {
    Object x()
}

class Y implements X {
    String x()
}
```

Comment: I have made a class and added implements InterfaceTest, with InterfaceTest containing one method called `int withdraw(int amount);` but I am still able to compile my class without adding this withdraw method to my original class, is that normal? In Eclipse it says at the top that there are unimplemented methods, but it still compiles.

Comment: @Kye It might be better to put the whole code in a new question. Possibly on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Kye make sure you're recompiling everything, especially if your interface is in a different library. Possible you're picking up old build artifacts...